# Set image directly to text field in custom keyboard iOS 8

Tags: ios, animated-gif, custom-keyboard

I have developed a sample application of custom keyboard extension in iOS8.0. In which I have achieved to copy and paste the selected image by using paste selection of text field (Message app, notes app).
But I am trying to directly set it to the text field or text view of the the respective apps. Is there any way by which I can avoid manual paste of images and set the image directly?

Comment: I've been attempting this since iOS8 BETA 2... still haven't found a way, I try again with each new update hahaha! If anyone finds a way please @notify me in this comments section :D

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw Have you find any solution for this keyboard . I want to create a custom emoji( My Image Keyboard ) so let me know how can i develop it ! if you find any way then let me know :)